# htaccess permissions randomly being used in parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, http-basic-authentication

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server, which I have had set up for a fews years with little adjustments. On the server I have a directory `Movies` which has a .htaccess file in it that requires authentication for viewing. Without touching the server or any files, the authentication from the .htaccess file in the `/Movies` is now being applied to the root, `/` and all of its subfolders. The `.htaccess` file does not contain any BasicAuth (Only the file in the `/Movies` directory.

How did this happen or more importantly, what can I do to fix this? The BasicAuth has worked great for years in the `/Movies` folder with it not asking for authentication from the root or other folders. I have checked the `.htaccess`and site config files and nothing has changed.

Here is the relevant chunk of the .htaccess file in question (`/Movies/.htaccess`):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Movies"
AuthUserFile /var/www/Movies/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=ALLOWED
Allow from env=ALLOWED2
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the suspect .htaccess file ?

Comment: @FelixJen Updated

Comment: the very design of .htaccess is meant to isolate from higher scopes...  i.e. its settings only apply to the directory hosting the file and sub-directories underneath. So it is not likely that your root is inheriting from a lower scope (/Movies/.htaccess), unless your site config or root .htaccess has an Include statement pointing to /Movies/.htaccess... which would be odd. Does your site config or root .htaccess have its own Auth settings? or any Rewrites, Redirects, Aliases...etc. that may be redirecting or mapping down into /Movies? Any clues from access or error logs?